# Find which heap an address belongs to?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

I'm creating a memory management system and i need a way to find in which heap an allocation I make is.
for example i use HeapAlloc and use the heap returned by GetProcessHeap() as the heap to allocate to I would expect it to allocate to that heap, but appears as though it doesn't.

When I use GetProcessHeaps to run through the heaps i find that the process heap is at something like 0x00670000 and my allocated address is at like 0x0243a385 or something. (in other words nowhere near it)
And sometimes it can actually be before it (so like 0x004335ab or something)

So, i'd like to know if there is a way I can reliably get the starting address of the heap (and the end address if at all possible!?) that i made the allocation in.

Comment: Why do you assume that the addresses returned by allocating using a heap have anything to do with where the heap is?

Comment: Well, I would assume that if you are allocating onto the heap then the address returned by the heapalloc function would be within the start and end boundaries of the heap? is that not correct?

Comment: What do you mean by 'start and end boundaries'. How are you calculating those?

Comment: That's my question. I only know the address of my allocation, but i'd like to know the address of the heap that it is allocated to. I have no idea where the 'start address' of the heap is and i have no idea where the 'last address' of the heap is (in other words startaddress + sizeofheap) is my understanding of the heap completely wrong?

Comment: OK I know understand. I'll add an answer.

Comment: sysinternalssuite vmmap - is not the answer to your question, but a useful tool to explore the memory allocated in a process. Might help you find your heaps and correlate things...

Comment: @ChrisBecke Thank you! that's a brilliant piece of software!

Comment: Are you sure you aren't confusing the heap **handle** with a memory address? I can't see any [Heap Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366781.aspx#heap_functions) that would return the starting address of a heap, given it's heap handle.

Comment: is the heap handle not essentially a pointer to the heap? in the same way that a handle to a window is just a pointer to a window object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of heaps is wrong. In general, modern heaps do not rely on allocating a large chunk of data and then parcelling it up with each allocation as you assume (although they may use this as one of their strategies). This means there is no well defined 'start' or 'end' of a heap. As an example, by default, with Windows heaps large allocations always go direct to the operating system via `VirtualAlloc(...)` which means that allocations from one heap may interleave with allocations from another.

If you really need to work out which heap an allocation comes from, there is a way, although its really slow so you shouldn't rely on it except for debugging or logging or similar. For actual, normal, code you should really *know* where allocations came from either via deduced context or by actually storing it.

Warnings aside, you can use [HeapWalk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee175819(v=vs.85).aspx) to enumerate all allocations from each heap looking for the one you want.

Comment: hmm, thank you for the answer! I didn't realise my understanding was wrong. So just 2 follow up questions if thats okay? 1. So is it possible that if i used HeapAlloc() twice with the same Heap Handle the allocations made wouldn't be continuous in memory? 2. Is there not one large part of the memory that is reserved exclusively for dynamic allocations then? like there is a part of memory reserved for code storage?

Comment: In general you cannot assume anything about the relationship between 2 address' returned from 2 different calls to HeapAlloc.Sometimes they'll be contiguous but that will change depending on a lot of different things. Try free'ing something between two calls. Try allocating on multiple threads. Try doing different sized allocations. Try setting variuos heap flags. This will ALL pertub the address' returned.

Comment: In general, no, there's no exclusive ranged marked for dynamic allocations. Theres just general unused range which can be picked up by a heap when it calls into the operating system to allocate some pages. Loading DLLs, creating threads (which will allocate a stack), etc, can all use that unused range aswell.

Comment: Okay thanks very much, that's all really helpful. It does mean i've gotta change the design of pretty much my entire management system, but still great to know :P thank you.